# бесконечный цикл turtle

Tags: python, координаты

Я недавно начал изучить питон и сделал для себя задание которое почти выполнил но осталось сделать только это. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы квадрат который рисует модуль turtle уходил по координатам бесконечно, есть координаты x(-1) y(1) и нужно чтобы значение x и y постоянно менялись автоматически. x(-2) y(2) и тд.

```
import turtle 

def move():
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)

def ds():
    for i in range(4):
        move()

tx = 1
ty = 1
 
def turt():
    ds()
    tx + (1)
    ty + (1)
    turtle.goto (tx,ty)
    turt()

turt()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import turtle 

def sqare(size):
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.left(90)

size = 10
x = 0
y = 0

while True:
    turtle.pendown()
    square(size)
    size += 10
    x -= 5
    y -= 5
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).